# prestashop How to find category id_image

Tags: smarty, prestashop

I have some subcategories and I just need to get the 'id_image' from their parent category. Is it possible?

I can get the parent category id '$id_category_parent' but from them I don't Know how to get the image.I Try:

```
$id_category->id_image
```

But obviously it doesn't work because $id_category_parent is not an object. I guess I am missing an 'smarty' function to get the object, but I don't understand it pretty well.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: On what page are you trying to do this? I don't think it's possible with smarty if you don't already have the object assigned from php.

Comment: I am doing this in the category page... what I want to do is that if the user do not upload a picture for the subcategories, it displays the parent category's image as default

Comment: Could you explain me better how to do it? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so I'm doing this by memory so I can't guarantee it's 100% correct but here is the idea. If you want to do this in the category page you can override `CategoryController.php`

```
/**
 * Overrides the init method
 * to get the parent category
 */
public function init() {
    parent::init();

    // I don't remember if it's id_parent or id_category_parent but this will be easy to find out
    $this->parent_category = new Category($this->category->id_parent, $this->context->language->id);
}

/**
 * Pass the variable to smarty
 */
public function initContent() {
    parent::initContent();

    $this->context->smarty->assign('parent_category', $this->parent_category);
}
```

Then in your template you can use the classic:

```
<img src="{$link->getCatImageLink($parent_category->name, $parent_category->id_category, 'home_default')}">
```

Something like this should work.

Comment: I am sorry for the late response, this is exactly what I needed!! It works perfectly, and also it Helps me to understand more how smarty works. Thanks a lot.